# What color code is this?

Tags: c#, excel, colors, header, spreadsheetgear

I'm looking at a code snippet which places text in an excel header:

`headerText.Append(@"&""Calibri""&20&K04-024HEADER-TEXT");`

`&""Calibri""` modifies the font, `&20` modifies the size, and `&K04-024` modifies the color (to navyish).

The question is, what kind of color code is this (`K04-024`)?  I've seen various types before but nothing like this.  I've tried scouring google and can't find anything about it.

EDIT:

This is C# using Spreadsheet Gear to drop text into an Excel header.  It turns out that: `&K01+047` is a medium grey color.  These numbers were figured out by examining an XML excel document and seeing what excel uses internally as colors.

EDIT:
For the RGB Scale:

`K04-024` translates to `R:045 G:107 B:181`

`K01+047` translates to `R:120 G:120 B:120`

Comment: What language is that calling `headerText.Append`?

Comment: Have you tried changing the code and seeing what you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>It looks like it's RGB with dash meaning an empty color, as `0x040024`/`R4 G0 B36` gives a navy color.</s>

**Edit in response to your edit:**
It looks like they're combined colors from a palette. See [here](http://support.softartisans.com/kbview_1205.aspx) for the list of colors and indices.

Comment: 4 is blue, 24 is dark blue. Result is navy. 1 is white, 47 is gray, result is medium gray.